# How to explain the error.thanks

Tags: swift

```
//习题 写一个计算参数平均值的函数
func cacuAver(numbers:Int...)->Int{
    var average=0
    var sum=0
    if (numbers.count!=0){
        for number in numbers{
            sum+=number
        }
        average =sum/numbers.count
    }
    return average 
}
```

at `if numbers.count!=0` statement an error occur, cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Int', but when I change to `if numbers.count==0`,the error disappear.

I want to know why and where I made mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple actually, as you know `!` and `?` is a syntax in Swift, so it is better to leave a space between those operator and it will no problem to do so, like `if numbers.count != 0`

`!` means there is definitely a value while `?` mean it is optional value. And error see your `numbers.count!` as 1 word instead of `!=`